# MaterialCalenderView - Make selected days, unselectable

Tags: android, calendar, material-design

I'm using the MaterialCalenderView Library. Is it possible to make selected days unselectable?

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

[image]

When I click on another date, it removes the current date. Is it possible to make the current date unselectable?

Comment: You can use the official MaterialDatePicker. It allows a validation.

Comment: it doesn't have that class https://i.imgur.com/GlDTRnA.png

Comment: The MaterialDatePicker is included in the Material Components Library version 1.1.0

Comment: I'm using 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Just type:

```
calendarEample.setDateSelected(yourdate, true);
```

or you can disable it:

```
binding.calendarViewSelecting.addDecorator(new DayViewDecorator() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
                            view.setDaysDisabled(true);
                        }
                    });
```